# how to set height of svg slope? here is my code

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to increase the width & height of the svg slope.

Here is my code.

```
 [https://codepen.io/hetal001/pen/pZWRYz][1]
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. -- *from the close reason*

Answer (score 0):

if you write this code you must know how to make this shape bigger
but for this arrow I suggest to use this code :

```css
div {
  margin-top:20px;
}
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.arrow-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  
  border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-left {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
  
  border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

it's very simple to customize

Comment: Thank you but I need rounded shape from the top.